# Python: How to convert Pandas Dataframe Row Values to individual columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.x

I have the following dataframe which has the data of different jobs start and end time at different intervals. A small part of dataframe is shown below.

**Dataframe(df):**

```
result | job   |  time
START  | JOB0  |  1357  
START  | JOB2  |  2405
END    | JOB2  |  2379
START  | JOB3  |  4010
END    | JOB0  |  5209
END    | JOB3  |  6578
START  | JOB0  |  6000
END    | JOB0  |  6100
```

(Note - Original Dataframe has 5 Jobs (JOB0 to JOB4)
I want to convert the values (`START` and `END`) of column `result` as individual columns in the dataframe.

**Required Dataframe(df2)**

```
job  |  START  | END
JOB0 |  1357   | 5209
JOB2 |  2405   | 2379
JOB3 |  4010   | 6578
JOB0 |  6000   | 6100
```

**Code**
I tried implementing this using a `pivot_table` but it is giving aggregated values which is not required.

`df2 = df.pivot_table('time', 'job','result')`

**Code Output**

```
result |       END       |      START
job     
JOB0   |    5.000589e+08    5.000636e+08
JOB1   |    4.999141e+08    4.999188e+08
JOB2   |    5.001668e+08    5.001715e+08
JOB3   |    4.995190e+08    4.995187e+08
JOB4   |    5.003238e+08    5.003236e+08
```

How can I attain the required dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You have repeated jobs(`JOB0`), So its better to create a unique id for the jobs then pivot it based on `id` and `job` like

```py
df['id'] = df.groupby(['job', 'result']).cumcount()
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['id','job'], columns='result', values='time')
```

Output:

```
result    END  START
id job              
0  JOB0  5209   1357
   JOB2  2379   2405
   JOB3  6578   4010
1  JOB0  6100   6000
```

Have the df sorted on `time` for sanity (There could be issues if the same jobs overlap each other)

```
df = df.sort_values(by='time')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) for this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = df.pivot(index="job", columns="result", values="time")
```